# Margins and padding on overlapping divs on Edge browser

Tags: html, css

Let me preface this by saying that I know that designing for Edge/Explorer is neigh impossible. But currently I have a situation where a fully functioning webpage on Chrome/Firefox shows literally nothing on Edge.

I have a background image which covers the whole page. Then there is a second div that is meant to be on top of it, that has a fading gradient below where the nav bar will be.

I've stripped out the relevant parts and linked to a placeholder image:

```
<html>
<style>
    .main-image{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background-image: url("https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/project-pokemon/images/4/47/Placeholder.png/revision/latest?cb=20170330235552");
        background-color:#192940;
        background-size: cover;
        z-index:50;
    }

    .fade{
        position:relative;
        top:-100%;
        width:100%;
        height:20%;
        margin-bottom:-100%;
        padding:0;
        margin-top:100px;
        background: linear-gradient(#242424, transparent);
    }
</style>


<div class="main-image"></div>
<div class="fade"></div>

</html>
```

The image div should be uncontraversial. It's a full page image and there's a background color for if the image takes long to load.

The fade div I move up by 100% to get it on top of the image. Then I reduce the bottom margin so that the page doesn't get a scroll bar. I think that the margin-bottom is what is messing up Explorer. But if I take it out then it doesn't display nicely on Chrome. I've played around with the margins and padding but I'm not coming right.

Which part of the CSS is being handled differently by edge? What alternative can I use? Is there a way to overlay one div on top of another that is cross-browser compatible.?

EDIT: For clarity, here's some pictures.

Here is what the website looks like on Chrome:

[image]

as you can see there is a main image, with a fade from the nav bar into the image. This is what I want to work in Edge as well.

This is what it currently looks like on edge:

[image]

Comment: what do you want, exactly? if you show what you want with a picture I can help you.

Comment: Okay will edit now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```html
<style>

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline:0;
    font-weight:bold;
    font: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.buffer {
    height:35px;
}


.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #203459;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin-top:0px;
    border:0;
    padding:0;

}


.sidenav a {
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    margin-top:0;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.top-nav {
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#242424;
}

.fader {
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background: linear-gradient(#242424, transparent)

}

.main-title {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#242424;
    z-index:10;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr, td, th {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;

}



.about ul li {
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:16px;
    padding-top:8px;
    color:white;
    font-size:1.4vw;
}

.nav {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:20;
    width:100%;
    height:35px;
    background-color:transparent;
    padding-left:12vw;
    margin-top:-10;
    border: 0;
}

.nav ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.nav ul li {
    list-style:none;
}

.nav ul li a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 2%;
    color: #DBD370;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:1.4vw;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #E5D83D;
    margin-top:-4px;
}

</style>



<div class="main-title">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <video style="height:90px;" autoplay>
                    <source src="/static/kraak/title.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    <p style="color:white">Your browser does not support video </p>
                </video>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="about">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Eco-Author
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td>
                <div class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/about_me/">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/books/">Books</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/media/">Media</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/inspirations/">Inspirations/Lines of Flight</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>






<style>
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border: 0;
}

.main_old {
    text-align: left;
    background: deepskyblue;
    filter: blur(5px);
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border: 0;
}

.background {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
    position:fixed;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border: 0;
}

.blur_background {
    width:100%;
    height:111.111111%;
    top:-9.5%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border: 0;
}

.mask {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:10;
    margin:0px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border: 0;
}

.def {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-color: black;
    color: black;
}

.fade{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    top:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-top:100px;
    background: linear-gradient(#242424,transparent);
}

body {
    height:100%;
}

.comment{
    background: linear-gradient(#DADBEC, transparent);
}

.main-image{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image: url("http://www.rouxnette.com/static/kraak/homefinalhighdef.jpg");
    background-color:#192940;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index:50;
}


</style>

<head>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-130569684-1"></script>
    <script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'UA-130569684-1');
    </script>

</head>






<div class="main-image"></div>
<div class="fade"></div>
```

this is works on edge:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the first time in my life I can say: "**Explorer/Edge are right!**"

**First and more important thing**: your page has a huge HTML problem. No `<body>` tag, `<head>` near the footer, `<style>` tags free to move everywhere... no, you have to use a correct structure (*for this I think Explorer is right to give you a white page ;-)* ).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- put here your styles -->

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- your body with your content -->


  </body>
</html>
```

**Second thing**: please (please!!), don't use `<table>` to create layout! We are in 2018 and we can use other solutions (flexbox, CSS grid layout... everything you want, but not `<table>`).

**Third thing**: you have a background-image of 731 KB weight! It is too big! You have to reduce its weight, it is not for a print...

Ok, having said that we can see your page:

I added `html{height:100%}` and put your `.fade` div in an absolute position, removing all margin negative and all work well (I changed your image so everyone can see it in this example, but you can use yours, naturally).

This is the page:

```css
html,
body {
 height: 100%;
}

* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 font-weight: bold;
 font: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.buffer {
 height: 35px;
}

.sidenav {
 height: 100%;
 width: 15%;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-color: #203459;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 margin-top: 0px;
 border: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.sidenav a {
 padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #818181;
 display: block;
 border: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
 color: #f1f1f1;
}

.top-nav {
 height: 100px;
 width: 200px;
 background-color: #242424;
}

.fader {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 background: linear-gradient(#242424, transparent)
}

.main-title {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: #242424;
 z-index: 10;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr,
td,
th {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
}

.about ul li {
 list-style: none;
 padding-left: 16px;
 padding-top: 8px;
 color: white;
 font-size: 1.4vw;
}

.nav {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 20;
 width: 100%;
 height: 35px;
 background-color: transparent;
 padding-left: 12vw;
 margin-top: -10;
 border: 0;
}

.nav ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.nav ul li {
 list-style: none;
}

.nav ul li a {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 padding: 0px 2%;
 color: #DBD370;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 1.4vw;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #E5D83D;
 margin-top: -4px;
}

.wrapper {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
}

.main_old {
 text-align: left;
 background: deepskyblue;
 filter: blur(5px);
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
}

.background {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
 position: fixed;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
}

.blur_background {
 width: 100%;
 height: 111.111111%;
 top: -9.5%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
}

.mask {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 10;
 margin: 0px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
}

.def {
 font-size: 24px;
 color: black;
}

.fade {
 position: relative;
 /*top:-100%;*/
 position: absolute;
 top: 100px;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20%;
 /*margin-bottom:-100%;*/
 padding: 0;
 /*margin-top:100px;*/
 background: linear-gradient(#242424, transparent);
}

.comment {
 background: linear-gradient(#DADBEC, transparent);
}

.main-image {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1170/875");
 background-color: #192940;
 background-size: cover;
 z-index: 50;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-title">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <video style="height:90px;" autoplay>
                        <source src="#" type="video/mp4">
                        <p style="color:white">Your browser does not support video </p>
                    </video>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="about">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                Eco-Author
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <div class="nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/about_me/">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/books/">Books</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/media/">Media</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/inspirations/">Inspirations/Lines of Flight</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="main-image"></div>
    <div class="fade"></div>
```

Comment: That's very helpful advice, thanks! I'm quite a newbie on frontend, I'm a backend developer by profession. Just doing this site for a friend. But eager to learn the best practices. So thanks again!